# pip list shows different packages installed when run from different directories

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment, lets call it `virtenv`.

After activating it (`workon virtenv`), running `pip list` or `pip freeze` shows a relatively short list of packages.

Running `which pip` shows `~/bin/pip`.

When entering the virtual envs package directory (`~/.../virtual_envs/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`), `pip list` and `pip freeze` show a much longer and more extensive list of packages.

Running `which pip` still shows `~/bin/pip`.

Since in both cases I'm in the same activated environment, and the same `pip` is being run, shouldn't the lists be the same?

EDIT: resolved. This file: `~/.pydistutils.cfg` caused pip to always run from `~/bin/pip` and that messed up the virtual environment.

Comment: You claim to have activated the virtual environment but apparently you haven't, as is confirmed by the output of `which pip`; what's the content of the `PATH` environment variable?. Please create a [verifiable and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that includes the setup and activation of your environment. Please also include information about your OS.

Comment: found the problem - `~/.pydistutils.cfg` (which I have no clue when how or why was ever created on this computer) had this line:
`install-scripts=$HOME/bin`

which caused pip to always run from that location, even when the virtual environment was activated. after deleting the file and reinstalling pip, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Does that also explain why `pip` showed different packages when run from different directories?

Comment: not sure if it really explains it, but it definitely fixed the issue for me so I don't really have a way of checking the root cause